# Converting simple makefile into CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: makefile, cmake, compiler-flags

I'm trying to convert this simple makefile into a CMakeLists.txt. I'm specifically struggling with the flags.

```
SOURCE = triangle.cpp shader.cpp
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lGLEW -lglfw
OBJECT = window

default:
    $(CC) -o $(OBJECT) $(SOURCE) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECT)
```

Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Graphics)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lGLEW -lglfw")

#add_definitions(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})

add_executable(
    trtangle
    triangle.cpp
)
```

Here's the error message I get:

```
Scanning dependencies of target triangle
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/triangle.cpp.o
clang: warning: -framework OpenGL: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -framework GLUT: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lGLEW: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lglfw: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/Users/neilculbertson/Desktop/OpenGL/triangle.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found
#include <GL/glew.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/triangle.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've also tried setting CMAKE_C_FLAGS But still no luck. Keep in mind when I use the makefile alone, everything compiles and works perfectly. I'm wondering if it's a GL error? or maybe I installed GLEW weirdly?

Answer (score 2):

cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)       # This line is required
project(triangle)                         # This line is required
```

make

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lGLEW -lglfw
```

cmake

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lGLEW -lglfw")
```

make

```
SOURCE = triangle.cpp shader.cpp
default:
    $(CC) -o $(OBJECT) $(SOURCE) $(CFLAGS)
```

cmake

```
# The name of the result and all required sources
add_executable(triangle triangle.cpp shader.cpp)

# These libraries are required
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 3.0 REQUIRED)

# ... and the path to the header files and so files 
target_include_directories(triangle  ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(triangle ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} glfw3)
```

Other possibility is to collect all sources within a list at first.

```
set(SOURCES triangle.cpp shader.cpp)
add_executable(triangle ${SOURCES)
```

make

```
OBJECT = window
```

cmake

- Not necessary

make

```
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECT)
```

cmake

- This is built in.

Comment: This won't work. You need to create the target first and then apply the `target_include_directories` or `target_link_libraries` commands.

Comment: I will rework it. But this makes it harder to compare it with the make file.

Comment: Instead of setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, CMake prefers you to use [add_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/add_compile_options.html) (and [add_compile_definitions()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/add_compile_definitions.html), if you need them).

Comment: ...And [target_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/target_compile_options.html) can be used to just set them for the target as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Graphics)

add_executable(
    trtangle
    triangle.cpp
)

target_compile_options(trtangle PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(trtangle  ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(trtangle ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} glfw)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. At first, CMake was complaining about the number of arguments for target_include_directories, so I put PUBLIC in there: target_include_directories(triangle PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}) But I'm still getting the same error saying that it can't find <GL/glew.h> Appreciate your help BTW!!